How do count button clicks on wordpress/elementor/jetengine and increment the count in a meta field
I want to count every time a specific button is pressed. I am using wordpress and the button is created using elementor, I then want to increment the count of a meta field using jetengine.
I have followed a tutorial and successfully been able to count every time a person clicks into a post, using this code:
function increment_post_views() {
    if (is_single()) {
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $views = get_post_meta($post_id, 'products_views', true);
        // If the 'post_views' meta field doesn't exist, initialize it to 1
        if (empty($views)) {
            $views = 1;
        } else {
            $views = intval($views) + 1;
        }
        // Update the 'post_views' meta field with the incremented value
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'products_views', $views);
    }
}
add_action('wp', 'increment_post_views');


Could anyone help me write a code snippet to track the button clicks? to my knowledge i will need to add some jquery to handle the click events and send the data to backend and update the meta fields using the same method? i have very little knowledge in coding so any help would be appreciated!

"successfully been able to count every time a person clicks into a post" - this is not actually counting "clicks", it is counting how many times the single post view of a specific post was requested from the server. For what you want, you should probably make your button make a request via AJAX in the background. If you are not familiar with using AJAX in WordPress, start by reading up on some basics: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/, https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/

ok this took me all day but i got working. If anyone has any comments to make this code better please do!  there is a lot of console messages in code but it helped with troubleshooting.
The highlighted terms here will need to be changed in the code to suit your application:
I created a custom post type using jetengine called industry-jobs. I then created a number meta field in this post type called click_count
I then created a button in elementor and assigned the CCS class as track-click-button and a custom attribute:
data-post-id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>"

I then created 3 snippets:
PHP snippet 1
function update_click_count() {
if (isset($_POST['post_id'])) {
    $post_id = intval($_POST['post_id']);

    // Validate that the post exists and is of the correct post type
    if (get_post_type($post_id) === 'industry-jobs') {
        // Get the current click count
        $current_count = (int) get_post_meta($post_id, 'click_count', true);

        // Increment the click count
        $new_count = $current_count + 1;

        // Update the meta field
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'click_count', $new_count);

        // Send success response
        wp_send_json_success(['new_count' => $new_count]);
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error('Invalid post type.');
    }
} else {
    wp_send_json_error('Missing post ID.');
}

wp_die(); // Required to terminate and return a proper response
}
add_action('wp_ajax_update_click_count', 'update_click_count');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_update_click_count', 'update_click_count');

PHP snippet 2
if (!function_exists('enqueue_combined_click_tracker_script')) {
function enqueue_combined_click_tracker_script() {
    if (is_singular('industry-jobs')) {
        // Register the JavaScript file that contains the tracking logic
        wp_register_script(
            'click-tracker-script',
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/click-tracker.js', // Adjust 
the path to your JavaScript file
            ['jquery'], // jQuery dependency
            null,
            true // Load in the footer
        );

        // Pass ajaxurl to the script
        wp_localize_script('click-tracker-script', 'clickTrackerData', [
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
        ]);

        // Enqueue the JavaScript file after localization
        wp_enqueue_script('click-tracker-script');

        // Inline JavaScript to set the post ID dynamically
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                const button = document.querySelector('.track-click-button');
                if (button) {
                    console.log('Inline JS: Button found');
                    button.setAttribute('data-post-id', '<?php echo 
get_the_ID(); ?>');
                } else {
                    console.error('Inline JS: Button not found');
                }
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_combined_click_tracker_script');
}

javascript snippet - put location to footer
console.log('click-tracker.js: Script is running');

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
console.log('click-tracker.js: jQuery document ready');

const button = $('.track-click-button');

if (button.length > 0) {
    console.log('click-tracker.js: Button found', button);

    button.on('click', function () {
        const postID = $(this).data('post-id');
        console.log('Button Clicked, Post ID:', postID);

        if (postID) {
            $.ajax({
                url: clickTrackerData.ajaxurl, // Use the localized ajaxurl
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    action: 'update_click_count',
                    post_id: postID,
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        console.log('Click count updated successfully');
                    } else {
                        console.error('Failed to update click count', 
response);
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.error('AJAX request failed:', status, error);
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.error('Post ID is missing from the button');
        }
    });
} else {
    console.error('click-tracker.js: Button not found');
}
});


You can track button clicks by using Ajax
Step 1 - function.php
function enqueue_custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_localize_script('custom-script', 'ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_scripts');

function increment_button_clicks() {
    if (isset($_POST['post_id'])) {
        $post_id = intval($_POST['post_id']);
        $button_clicks = get_post_meta($post_id, 'button_clicks', true);
        
        if (empty($button_clicks)) {
            $button_clicks = 1;
        } else {
            $button_clicks = intval($button_clicks) + 1;
        }
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'button_clicks', $button_clicks);
        echo $button_clicks;
    }
    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_increment_button_clicks', 'increment_button_clicks');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_increment_button_clicks', 'increment_button_clicks');

Step 2: Add data-post-id to your button.
data-post-id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>"

Step 3: Create custom.js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $(".your-button-class").on("click", function () {
    var postID = $(this).data("post-id");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
      data: {
        action: "increment_button_clicks",
        post_id: postID,
      },
      success: function (response) {
        console.log("Button click recorded: " + response);
      },
      error: function (error) {
        console.log("Error recording button click: ", error);
      },
    });
  });
});

